# Set Session Variable In MVC View and DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How can i set a Session value in the MVC View from Javascript in a DateTimePicker?

I have this code:

```
if('@Session["Data"]'==""){
  $('#datetimepicker').datepicker('setDate', startDate); @Session["Data"] = startDate;}
  else { $('#datetimepicker').datepicker('setDate', '@Session["Data"]'); }
```

This code work fine but the code

```
@Session["Data"] = startDate;
```

not working. How can i save Data here?

Thank you to all

Answer (score 0):

Your C# Code in your razor view gets executed in server. But your javascript code executes on client. So you cannot set a c# variable value inside your javascript like what you have in your question.

What you can do is make an ajax call to an endpoint and set the value in session there. So create an action method to handle the ajax call

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetDate(DateTime date)
{
  // Set to session here
  return Json( new { Status="Success"});
}
```

Now from your javascript code, use ajax to call this endpoint and pass the date value.

```
var startDate= "Read the date value here";
$.post("YourControllerName/SetDate", { date = startDate},function(r){
    if(r.Status==="Success")
    {
      alert("Date is now in session")
    }
});
```

You may consider using the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the path o the action method instead of hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

You're merging javascript and c# code.

You can't set the startDate (javascript) to Session (c#) because javascript runs on client side.

If **startDate** is equals to **DateTime.Now** it'll help you.

```
<script>
    if('@Session["Data"]'===""){
        $('#datetimepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date()); 
        @(Session["Data"] = DateTime.Now);
    } else {
        $('#datetimepicker').datepicker('setDate', '@Session["Data"]'); 
    }
</script>
```